# How to change the color of the status bar in nautilus file (nautilus.rc)?

Tags: nautilus

I am editing a theme, manages to change the color of the sidebar, but I can not change the color of the status bar has the same color as the sidebar, and I want the status bar in white without changing the color of the sidebar

How do I change nautilus.rc to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what nautilus.rc is, but to change the background color of the Nautilus status bar, you can add this to your `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
style "nautilus-statusbar"
{
    bg[NORMAL]        = "#00ff00"
}

widget_class "Nautilus*GtkStatusbar*" style "nautilus-statusbar"
```

Comment: thanks it worked! Can you help me take the edge off the status bar, leaving only the left side which is next to sidebar

Comment: like this http://img714.imageshack.us/i/nautilus1.png/ tank you, and put the slide zoom bar in white too?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done by theming alone. Anyway, I suggest you make this separate questions. :) Also, if you want to accept my answer, click on the checkbox icon left of it. :)